# Convert only all-uppercase lines to lower-case

Tags: text-processing, sed

As an example, say I have:

```
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
ONE, TWO.
```

And I want to replace only the lines with all upper-case with lower case so that I get:

```
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.
```

I am trying:

```
gsed '/[a-z]/!c\L&'
```

It's matching the lines correctly, but replacing them with: L&

```
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
L&
```

How do I get it convert to lower case?

I tried 2 or 3 backslashes before the L but it just puts them in the output.

I will use awk or tr or some other utility if there's a better choice.

Also, if the version matters:

```
gsed --version
gsed (GNU sed) 4.9
```

Comment: Do you need to handle ÜNICØDÉ ? (thx @Philippos for this text!).

Answer (score 18):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '!/[[:lower:]]/ { $0=tolower($0) } 1' file
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to use `s///` for `&` to work, e.g.:

```
$ sed -e '/[a-z]/!s/.*/\L&/' < test.txt
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.
```

You could do the same or similar with Perl (which might be available where GNU sed isn't):

```
% perl -pe 's/.*/\L$&/ if not /[[:lower:]]/' < test.txt
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.
```

or:

```
% perl -pe '$_ = lc if not /[[:lower:]]/' < test.txt
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.
```

Comment: For standard `sed`, the `y` command is the tool of choice. Unfortunally, it doesn't accept character collections like `[A-Z]`. Thus, you need some support by the shell: `sed "/[a-z]/! y/$(printf %s {A..Z} / {a..z})/"`

Comment: @Philippos, and then you get to the issue that brace expansion isn't a standard feature, so you'd need to just spell out the list ;)

Answer (score 5):

With `Perl`'s ternary operator:

```
$ perl -ne 'print /[a-z]/ ? $_ : lc' file
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.
```

##### Explanations

| Operator | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `perl` | executable |
| `-n` | parse current file content as if we use `while (<>) ...` |
| `-e` | Perl's `e`xpression |
| `print` | print |
| `/regex/ ? :` | ternary operator, based on the matching of boolean result of the `regex` |
| `/[a-z]/` | if there's a lower case matching... |
| `$_` | ...then print current default variable of current line `$_` |
| `lc` | ...else print the current line in `l`ower `c`ase (implicit use of `$_`) |

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in perl:

```
$ perl -pe '$_ = lc() if /^[A-Z., ]+$/' file 
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.
```

The options are `-e` to pass a script, and `-p` to print every line of the input after applying the script given by `-e` to it. The script itself uses the special variable `$_` which means "the current line" and it converts it to lowercase (`lc` prints its input string in lower case, and by default, it acts on `$_`) only if the current line contains nothing but capital letters, spaces, commas and full stops (`/^[A-Z., ]+$/`).

---

If you go for a perl approach, use [Ilkkachu's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743856/22222) instead of mine since his doesn't depend on defining acceptable characters, and instead works by looking for lower case ones specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my (short and sweet) Perl solution:

```
perl -wpe '$_ = lc unless m/[a-z]/' file.txt
```

High-level explanation:  This is simply saying:  Before printing out each line in file `file.txt`, convert the line to lowercase *unless* it contains any lower-case letters.

You can also replace `m/[a-z]/` with `tr/a-z//` so that it looks like this:

```
perl -wpe '$_ = lc unless tr/a-z//' file.txt
```

The difference between them is that `m/[a-z]/` is meant to be evaluated as a boolean (that is, whether or not it contains the characters `a` thru `z`), whereas `tr/a-z//` returns the *number* of characters in the range of `a` thru `z`.  (If it returns a number greater than zero, then the lower-casing (that is, `$_ = lc`) will *not* happen.)

Which one is better?  I haven't benchmarked them, but the difference is probably so small that it's better to just use whichever one you're more comfortable with.

But remember:  The `m/[a-z]/` approach uses the `[` and `]` square brackets, whereas the `tr/a-z//` approach does not, but ends with two `/`s in a row.  It may be a bit much to remember both, so I recommend using whichever one is easier for you to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'if / <:Ll> / { $_.put } else { $_.lc.put };'  file

#OR (more simply)

~$ raku -ne 'put / <:Ll> / ?? $_ !! $_.lc;'  file
```

The first two answers below use Raku's `-ne` non-autoprinting command line switches. The regex character class `<:Ll>` stands for  "Unicode Letter lower". The first answer above is obviously an `if/else` construct. The second answer uses Raku's ternary operator ( < test > `??` True `!!` False ).

*MORE SOLUTIONS:*

```perl
~$ raku -e 'for lines() { when / <:Ll> / {.put}; default {$_.lc.put} };'  file 

#OR

~$ raku -pe '$_ .= lc if not / <:Ll> /;'  file
```

The third answer (first line in code block immediately above) uses Raku's "case" statement construction: `when` and `default` are used to satisfy the substitution criteria.

The fourth answer (second line in code block immediately above) uses Raku's `-pe` autoprinting (sed-like) command line flags, in conjunction with Raku's `.=` ***mutating***-assignment operator.

---

Sample Input:

```
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
ONE, TWO.

ÜNICØDÉ
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК RUSSIAN
ΝΈΑ ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΆ GREEK
"HEISS HEIẞ" GERMAN (WORD)
```

Sample Output (all code examples):

```
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.

ünicødé
русский язык russian
νέα ελληνικά greek
"heiss heiß" german (word)
```

The Raku answers handle Unicode (tested briefly above). For example, in the last line note the uppercase German `ẞ` (U+1E9E) is successfully converted to lowercase German `ß` (U+00DF). (This lettercasing was adopted into Unicode in 2008 and according to Wikipedia, "The capital letter was finally adopted as an option in standard German orthography in 2017.").

https://raku.org
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_??_!!
https://docs.raku.org/language/control#when
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ß#Development_of_a_capital_form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Development_of_a_capital_form)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Python as follows:

Create a Python script

```
 % cat all_upper_to_lower.py 
import sys

data = sys.stdin.readlines()
for line in data:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    new_line = line.lower() if line.isupper() else line
    print(new_line)
```

Create some sample data

```
 % cat input.txt 
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
ONE, TWO.
```

Run the script

```
 % cat input.txt | python all_upper_to_lower.py 
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ruby:

```
ruby -lpe ' $_=$_.downcase unless /[[:lower:]]/' file
```

Prints:

```
One, Two.
OnE, Two.
one, two.
```

How this works:

1. Command line switches `-lpe` do the following:

   -l `chomp` the line ending;

   -p Put a `while gets(); ... end` for sed like processing;

   -e Execute the script in the string following
2. `$_=$_.downcase` make the line of input lowercase before printing
3. `unless /[[:lower:]]/` If there is any lowercase, do not call `downcase`. You could also negate and do `if !/[[:lower:]]/`

And you can do something similar in Perl:

```
perl -lpE '$_=lc $_ unless /[[:lower:]]/' file 
# same
```